# Geting list of hmaps where containing all tags of a user

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap, hashtag

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w02Lx.png)The problem is when adding a new hmap, its elements are added to the oldest ones. How can I get list of hmaps where each one contain all tags of a user?

```
public List<HashMap<String, String>>tag_pp_user(String name,List<String> c) throws TwitterException, IOException, InterruptedException{ 
              List<HashMap<String, String>> c4 = new ArrayList<>();
              // c4 id a list of hashmap where each hashmap must contain the hahstags of a user wherr the key is the hashtag and the value is the name of the user
              HashMap<String, String> hmap = new HashMap<String, String>();          
        if (c.size()>40) {
            // c is a list of friends where i'm searching the tags of  each c.get(j) and i need just 40 friend
            for(int j=0;j<40;j++){
                hmap=hashtag_user(c.get(j));
                c4.add(hmap);  }
            }
        else {
            
            for(int j=0;j<c.size();j++){
                hmap=hashtag_user(c.get(j));
                System.out.println(hmap.size());
                c4.add(hmap);     
             }  
        }
   
        // when i view c4 i find that the new hashmap is added in the previous hmaps  
        return c4;
   
 }
```

[the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBID7.png)

```
public HashMap<String, String> hashtag_user(String name) throws TwitterException, IOException {
```

List  l= new ArrayList();
HashMap<String, String> hmap = new HashMap<String, String>();

```
Paging page = new Paging(1,200);
int p=1;
while(p<=10){
    page.setPage(p);
    
    statuses.addAll(twitter.getUserTimeline(name,page));
    
    p++;
} 
   for(Status s:statuses){
      
                    HashtagEntity[]  hts =s.getHashtagEntities(); //hmap.clear();
                   
                  // System.out.println(s.getText());
                            if ( hts.length > 0) {
                               // hmap.clear();
                               for(int j =0;j<hts.length;j++){//contains(hts[j].getText())
                                 //  if(!hmap.containsKey(hts[j].getText()))//{
                                  // System.out.println("**********"+hts[j].getText());
                                
                        if( !hts[j].getText().equals("hashtag") && !hts[j].getText().equals("tweet") && !hts[j].getText().equals("RT") && !hts[j].getText().equals("rt") && !hts[j].getText().equals("https")&& !hts[j].getText().equals("HTTPS")){
                                //System.out.println("**********"+hts[j].getText());
                                
                                 hmap.put(hts[j].getText(),name);//}
                                
                           
                              }
                               }
                            
                            
                               }   // System.out.println(hts.length);  
                       //Collections.unmodifiableMap(hmap);
                               
   }

 return hmap; 
  }
```

Comment: Please reformat your question to properly show the code!

Comment: Intialize `HashMap` inside for loop for both if-else  `HashMap<String, String> hmap = new HashMap<String, String>()` Currently all hashmap have same refference

Comment: that gives the same problem https://i.stack.imgur.com/w02Lx.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that you are using same reference hmap for the Object, which is outside of for loop and its not local to that for loop, and the reference will have the latest object pointed by hmap...to protect it, create every time new HashMap whenever you are going to add to list!!!

```
 public List<HashMap<String, String>>tag_pp_user(String name,List<String> c) throws TwitterException, IOException, InterruptedException{ 
                  List<HashMap<String, String>> c4 = new ArrayList<>();
                  // c4 id a list of hashmap where each hashmap must contain the hahstags of a user wherr the key is the hashtag and the value is the name of the user
                  //HashMap<String, String> hmap = new HashMap<String, String>();          
            if (c.size()>40) {
                // c is a list of friends where i'm searching the tags of  each c.get(j) and i need just 40 friend
                for(int j=0;j<40;j++){
                    //HashMap<String, String> hmap = new HashMap<String, String>();                        
                    //hmap=hashtag_user(c.get(j));
                    c4.add(hashtag_user(c.get(j)));  }
                }
            else {
                
                for(int j=0;j<c.size();j++){
                    //HashMap<String, String> hmap = new HashMap<String, String>();          
                    //hmap=hashtag_user(c.get(j));
                    //System.out.println(hmap.size());
                    c4.add(hashtag_user(c.get(j)));     
                 }  
            }
       
            // when i view c4 i find that the new hashmap is added in the previous hmaps  
            return c4;
       
     }
```

Comment: I tried this statement but it gives the same result https://i.stack.imgur.com/w02Lx.png

Comment: @amelahlem I have updated code, please use the code...you can directly add to the c4 list, because "hashtag_user(c.get(j))" will return map which you can add to c4 list